# Problem parsing JSON data into Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cryptography

I am trying to use a Crypto DEX api to pull the price pair name and current price data for every pair on the exchange and put it into 2 columns in Google Sheets, one fo the pair name and the other for the price. I've used ChatGPT to convert some code from the DEX team into a version compatible with Google Sheets (via Google App Script), but the data is missing the second column so it looks like there is a problem with parsing the data.

```
The original script is as follows:

curl -X POST https://api.hyperliquid.xyz/info \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{ "type": "allMids" }'
```

When converted using ChatGPT I get this:

```
function getHyperliquidData() {
  try {
    // Create the payload for the API request
    var payload = {
      type: 'allMids'
    };

    // Convert the payload to JSON string
    var payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);

    // Set up options for the HTTP request
    var options = {
      method: 'post',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      payload: payloadString
    };

    // Make the API request
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.hyperliquid.xyz/info', options);

    // Parse the API response
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    // Log the API response (optional)
    Logger.log('API Response:', data);

    // Write the data to the Google Sheet
    writePairsInfoToSheet(data);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error fetching API data:', error);
    // Handle the error as needed
  }
}

function writePairsInfoToSheet(pairsInfo) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Clear existing data
  sheet.clear();

  // Write header row
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue('Pair');
  sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue('Last Price');

  // Start from the second row
  var row = 2;

  // Iterate through pairs and write data to the sheet
  for (var pair in pairsInfo) {
    sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(pair);
    sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(pairsInfo[pair].px); // Assuming the price is available as 'px'

    row++;
  }
}
```

The result shows the pairs names in column 1 as expected, but the Price column is blank. Any help on how I can fix it would be great. I've looked at historical examples and they dont seem to quite match as I'm not getting any errors, just a partial lack of data.

Comment: See the logs. Post it here... What does the data actually look like?

Comment: I've managed to sort it now via posting a snippet of the output into ChatGPT. There was an issue with how the data was being extracted to Sheets

Answer (score 0):

The answer was based in showing ChatGPT the output of the Logger API and using the response to identify the correct Propery names needed, and then showing it a snippet again to help it correctly parse the information to the Sheet

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).